# How to intercept ActionMailer's messages on rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm trying to intercept messages in my rails (3.0.10) app to modify the body. While I was able to find some info about how to do that, it seems something has changed and now using the old methods no longer work.

I use a code that looks like this:

```
class Hook
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.subject = 'Hook changed the subject'
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(Hook)
```

After sending an email, the subject doesn't get changed!

I also found [a tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/jpignata/status/74094239348301824) that indicates that interceptors are not called when using the `deliver` method on messages, but the [premailer-rails3](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3) gem uses the same approach I used and  it works there (The plugin specifically mentions it works with the `deliver` method)!

I'm out of ideas here, so what is causing my problem?

Comment: Where is your `Hook` class defined, and where are you calling the `register_interceptor` method from?

Comment: It's inside a file in the `lib` dir. The `register_interceptor` gets called right after the class definition. I load all my libs using an initializer. I also made sure it's loaded by making an undefined Class and sure enough rails told me about it, so I'm sure it's getting loaded.

Comment: Have you tried putting a logger statement in your `delivering_email` method to make sure it's even getting called?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it does not get called. This confirms the tweet I mentioned above, but how does it work then for the premailer gem?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. I'd recommend posting the code of your `lib` file that has this code, as well as posting the code you're using to require this lib file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like it might be an order of operations problem.

Have you considered putting the entire code block you referenced in an initializer like `config/initializers/mail_hook.rb`?

If that premailer plugin works, the only difference I can think of is when the interception hook is registered in the app initialization process.

Answer (score 5):

see RailsCast or AsciiCast Episode #206

http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Relevant part from the first episode,

**/lib/development_mail_interceptor.rb**

```
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.subject = "[#{message.to}] #{message.subject}"
    message.to = "eifion@asciicasts.com"
  end
end
```

**/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb**

```
Mail.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if Rails.env.development?
```