# Rails 3 send emails in development to a single address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

In my Rails 2 apps I always used [sanitize email](https://github.com/pboling/sanitize_email) to send all emails in development to my personal account to avoid accidentally sending out emails or to use just for testing.

This doesn't seem to have a Rails 3 version and wondered if there was anything for Rails 3 that does this.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [How to intercept ActionMailer's messages on rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7272960/163640). You'll only have to add `message.to = my@email` and the mail will be sent to your email address instead of the original destination.

---

This is what I ended up doing from the post linked to above:

```
if Rails.env.development?
    class Hook
        def self.delivering_email(message)
            message.to  = "\"#{message.to.first}\" <my@email.com>"
            message.cc  = nil if !message.cc.nil?
            message.bcc = nil if !message.bcc.nil?
        end
    end

    ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(Hook)
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is incredibly useful for development.

Comment: You might want to use `Mail.register_interceptor(Hook)` instead of `ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(Hook)`

Answer (score 4):

Ryan Bates(Railscasts) has just released a gem for handling dev emails.

[Letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener)

Haven't used it but probably worth a look.